# Error while compiling apache APR make file not found

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, configure, apr

I tried to compile apache [APR](http://apr.apache.org/). The [instruction](http://apr.apache.org/compiling_unix.html) sayed:

All you should have to do is this:

```
 ./configure
  make
  make install
```

After ./compile I get the following output:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating include/apr.h
config.status: creating build/apr_rules.mk
config.status: creating build/pkg/pkginfo
config.status: creating apr-1-config
config.status: creating apr.pc
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/internal/Makefile
config.status: creating include/arch/unix/apr_private.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
rm: cannot remove `libtoolT': No such file or directory
config.status: executing default commands
config.status: include/apr.h is unchanged
config.status: include/arch/unix/apr_private.h is unchanged
```

When I try to do "make" the make file could not be found:

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Interesting, I'm just now compiling APR 1.7.0, this error still pops up! From what I understand, it's a bug, so you wonder why it hasn't been fixed in 6 years time...

Comment: @kasimir Yes. I don't believe it's a bug in the first case and there's something else we're not seeing. Also, even if i hack it, the make fails on macOS Big Sur. "error: Can not determine the proper size for pid_t"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit your configure file

Change the line

> $RM "$cfgfile"

to

> $RM -f "$cfgfile"

This will resolve the error

> rm: cannot remove `libtoolT': No such file or directory

Then try run configure. That's it

Comment: well there is another bug see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092461/error-while-installing-apache-apr-ranlib-file-usr-local-apr-lib-libtcnative-1

Comment: Why this bug is still there?

Comment: I think they have fixed it in latest packages.. though I didnt checked it in recent past.

Comment: @c0rp - Good question! Just saw it in 1.5.2.

Answer (score 14):

Just running:

```
touch libtoolT
```

is sufficient to get it to build correctly. If you really want to edit the configure file to avoid the delete you can do that, but giving it a file to remove works too.

Answer (score 4):

On apr-1.5.1 ,edit line 30145 of configure from

i.e `bash# vi +30145 configure`

`$RM "$cfgfile"`

to

`$RM -f "$cfgfile"`