# Error when installing Apache on Tomcat7: "file...has no symbols"

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, apr

I tried to install apache [APR][1] on Tomcat7.

What I did was:

```
tar xvf apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --without-ssl
make install
```

APR was not installed correctly I get the output:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `local-all'.
/usr/local/apr/build-1/mkdir.sh /usr/local/apr/include/apr-1 /usr/local/apr/lib/pkgconfig \
             /usr/local/apr/lib /usr/local/apr/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tcnative.pc /usr/local/apr/lib/pkgconfig/tcnative-1.pc
list=''; for i in $list; do \
        ( cd $i ; make DESTDIR= install ); \
    done
/bin/sh /usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 libtcnative-1.la /usr/local/apr/lib
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.0.dylib /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.0.dylib
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/apr/lib && { ln -s -f libtcnative-1.0.dylib libtcnative-1.dylib || { rm -f libtcnative-1.dylib && ln -s libtcnative-1.0.dylib libtcnative-1.dylib; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.lai /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 .libs/libtcnative-1.a /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.a
ranlib: file: /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.a(sslutils.o) has no symbols
```

What is wrong here?

When running Tomcat I get the following output:

```
Aug 07, 2013 2:16:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
```

Comment: Did you got any other error at the time of make or configure. Looks like the pasted snippet doesn't contain any errors.

Comment: I updated my question see the tomcat output. What is needed here?

Comment: Try yum install tomcat-native

Comment: just execute this in command line  "yum install tomcat-native -y"

Comment: What is yum? Is there another way?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I believe you are using centos so use yum to install package from repository. If you are using debian or ubuntu, you needed to use apt-get for the same

Comment: No I use Ubuntu. What should I use there?

Comment: @LeoPrince what should I do on Ubuntu?

Comment: Usually in ubuntu, Instead of "yum" you should use "apt-get" to install packages from repository. As per your other [forum update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109722/an-incompatible-version-1-1-22-of-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-is/18112713#18112713), I guess that your issue with tomcat-native has been fixed. Let us know if anything left :)

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109722/an-incompatible-version-1-1-22-of-the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-is/18112713#18112713

Comment: the solution at the last answer is working!