# An incompatible version 1.1.22 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.24

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, apr

I installed apache apr on ubuntu 10.04 with

```
sudo apt-get install libtcnative-1
```

When I stated my tomcat I got the following error:

```
Aug 07, 2013 6:57:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.22 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.24
```

How do I have to fix that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a script for compiling Apache Tomcat Native library:

```
#!/bin/bash

export APR_PATH=/usr/bin/apr-1-config
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat
export INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr

wajig install libaprutil1-dev make

cd /tmp
rm -Rf tomcat-native-*
tar -zxf $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz
cd /tmp/tomcat-native-*/jni/native

./configure --with-apr=$APR_PATH --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX
make && make install
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to upgrade your Tomcat native library to a newer version:

> sudo apt-get upgrade libtcnative-1

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: This line of code should upgrade Tomcat native library. I had similar problem.

Comment: does it increments the tomcat version or it updates to the latest available patch ?

Answer (score 1):

From the error its clear that your tomcat native is of older version (1.1.22) and service looks for much newer version at least 1.1.24. The latest and stable version of tomcat native is 1.1.27. You can install that. Use the following [link](http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204) to install and fix your current issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that by installing apr from source and then specify in your setenv the path to library . 
Set this in your setenv.sh

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/apr/lib'
```

You can follow more here
http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204